# Clang does not recognize nested class when used in a base class

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, clang

The following example does not compile in recent versions of clang, gcc versions work fine:

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct Base{};

template<typename T>
struct Derived: public Base<typename Derived<T>::WrappedT>{
    struct WrappedT{};
};

int main(){

}
```

[Live example on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/cPMoMfja4).

```
clang: error: no type named 'WrappedT' in 'Derived<T>'
```

For ordinary types, both compilers fail with a similar error as clang did, gcc complains about incomplete type.

```
template<typename T>
struct Base{};


struct Derived: public Base<Derived::WrappedT>{
    struct WrappedT{};
};

int main(){

}
```

[Live example on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/Meo9TTjfr).

**Which compiler is correct?** I suspect clang is correct and gcc works only due to some implementation details in two-phase name lookup for templates.

I know I can pull `WrappedT` outside but in my code there isn't only one `T` and this version would save me some typing and improve readability.

Comment: Incomplete type, as for CRTP, so clang is correct. Not sure diagnostic is required, so maybe gcc is right too ;-)

Comment: I think [this](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class#mem.general-7) is the reason clang rightly rejects the code.  I would a agree with a bug in the two phase process.

Comment: @NathanOliver Pity, if you just put it into an answer, I will accept. Jarod42: Thanks, yes you are right, that is similar.

Comment: The most obvious workaround is to introduce another base class template which can define `WrappedT` before the definition of `Derived`.